# Hide/fold matching braces in text mode

Tags: hideshow

I have free-form text logs with JSON-ish objects that I would like to selectively hide when analyzing the logs. They look something like this

```
2018-10-09 09:47:34.269 [T] T {

2018-10-09 09:47:34.269 [T] T   {

2018-10-09 09:47:34.269 [T] T      foo

2018-10-09 09:47:34.269 [T] T   }

2018-10-09 09:47:34.269 [T] T }
```

and I might want to collapse the inner pair and not show the line with `foo` on it, for example.

As far as I can figure out, `hideshow.el` does this, but I have not managed to enable it for text mode. I have the following in my `.emacs`

```
(defvar hs-special-modes-alist
      '((c-mode "{" "}" "/[*/]" nil nil)
        (text-mode "(" ")" "{" "}" "\[*\]" nil nil)))
```

which Emacs swallows, but if I try to enable `hs-minor-mode` while in text mode I still get `Text Mode doesn’t support Hideshow Minor Mode`. I cannot figure out what the `nil`s are for here, or how many I should have (if any).

I don't necessarily have to use hideshow if that is the wrong package to use for this.

**Solution**

Solved by negas answer below.
`comment-start` defines what a comment looks like, which I don't need, but it needs to be set for hideshow to be happy. I solved my problem by setting `comment-start` to something that won't likely occur in my logs:

```
(setq-local comment-start "///COMMENT")
```

Comment: I'll remove the `purecopy` since it's useless (it's only meaningful for code executed while building the `emacs` executable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the text-mode buffer where your log is, set `comment-start`.

`hideshow` checks this and `comment-end` at the beginning of `hs-grok-mode-type()`. `hs-grok-mode-type()` says:

```
Set up hideshow variables for new buffers.
If `hs-special-modes-alist' has information associated with the
current buffer's major mode, use that.
Otherwise, guess start, end and `comment-start' regexps; `forward-sexp'
function; and adjust-block-beginning function.
```

`text-mode` doesn't set `comment-start` (it's `nil`), and without it, `hideshow` cant do it's "guessing".

Answer (score -1):

HideShow is meant to hide comment (or comment-like) text, which would involve having a language syntax. Text mode doesn't have such a syntax.

Comment: I thought that the hs-special-modes-alist was there to define the syntax. I clarified that I don't have to use hideshow necessarily, it's just the package that seemed closest to what I want.

Comment: Hideshow _can_ hide comment text. From the first sentence of its [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hideshow.html) "allows you to selectively display portions of a program, which are referred to as blocks". Comments are just blocks, as are C functions, and Lisp sexps.